# Service notification automatically gets hidden after few minutes in Android 11

Tags: java, android, service, android-notifications, exoplayer

I am having a music player which shows notification using Exoplayer's Player Notification Manager from a service but the notification is automatically getting hidden after some minutes of posting. Again the notification gets shown once the state of the player gets changed, for example if I pause the audio the notification reappears on its own. I have tested it using default android's notification also but still having the same issue.
Below is the code used in the project -

```
private void createNotification() {
    PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener listener = new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId, boolean dismissedByUser) {
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
            startForeground(notificationId, notification);
        }
    };
    playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(new DescriptionAdapter())
            .setNotificationListener(listener)
            .setCustomActionReceiver(new CustomActionReceiver())
            .build();
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
        mediaSessionConnector = new MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession);
        mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(Constant.exoPlayer);
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(Constant.exoPlayer);
   }
```

I am calling the above method from `onCreate()` of the service.

Can anyone please help me in this. I am not getting any idea to solve it from last 2 days.

Comment: is this helpful? [Android 11's media controls can be completely dismissed after the December patch](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/12/14/android-11s-media-controls-can-be-completely-dismissed-after-the-december-patch/)

Comment: @Jabbar Actually this is something else what you have shared. My problem is the notification gets disappear after sometime from posting the notification

Answer (score 0):

add `setChannelNameResourceId​(channelNameResourceId)` and `setChannelImportance​(NotificationUtil.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)`

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried even using `setOnging(true)` and using android's default notification

Comment: can you please give me an another way to fix it